# Highcharts enabled legends = false, if not active

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highcharts it is possible to hide the legends if i set enabled to false:

```
legend: {
enabled: false
}
```

Is there a way to just hide legends if they are selected?

Comment: what do you mean by `inactive` in here

Comment: when its not selected, so the seria of this legend is not shown

Comment: Hi @Pseudalitos, Could you describe more precisely what is the result that you want to achieve? Do you want to just hide some series in legend? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/en2pq0xb/

Comment: i want to export the chart. Before i do an update of the chart to insert a title... in addition i want to remove the legends from the series which are not shown.

Comment: Hi @Pseudalitos, Sorry for the late response. Do you want to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fx462cp7/ ?